# How to autologin to Mikrotik hotspot with Tomato Shibby?

Tags: wireless

I would like to to login automatically on Mikrotik's hotspot using a router with Tomato Shibby firmware.

Comment: this is off topic here, please ask tomato firmware questions on [Su]

Comment: ok sorry, didn't know that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule the following script on `Administration`/`Scheduler`

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo "POST /login HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.16.1 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: 10.22.0.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 35

username=adrianoimba2&password=5149"| nc 10.22.0.1 80'
```